# Accessing a value returned by Stored Procedure in MYSQL in C# code

Tags: c#, mysql

So this is the C# code I'm using to pass the parameter StudentID. If StudentID exists in the database, new books would not be issued.

```
using (MyDBQuery query = new MyDBQuery("stpIsStudentIDPresent"))
            {
                query.AddVariableCharPara("?uStudentID", 100, studentID);
                query.ExecNonQuery();
                return Convert.ToInt32(query.GetReturnParaValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
```

and the Stored Procedure is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `stpIsStudentIDPresent`(IN uStudentID varchar(100), OUT studentCount INT )
BEGIN     
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO studentCount 
    FROM student_ID 
        WHERE student_ID=uStudentID ;
END
```

Would something as simple as

```
int count = Student.isStudentIDPresent(studentID);
```

enable me to get the count value?

Comment: That seems likely - although I'd rename the method to indicate that it returns an `int` rather than a `bool`, and to follow .NET naming conventions. What happens when you try your current code?

Comment: count comes as 0 even for an existing student ID.

Comment: I would suggest adding that detail into the question then - along with details of `MyDBQuery` and `GetReturnParaValue`. It's entirely possible that it's that layer that's causing the problem, but it's hard to tell without more information.